# What is baseline android in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

**BaseLine**

When set to false, prevents the layout from aligning its children's baselines.

I don't get that give me a visual example please and also about `android:baselineAlignedChildIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an image of a baseline example in buttons in a linear horizontal oriented layout.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

check out this image: [android:baselineAlignedChildIndex example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymukX.jpg).I got the image from [this](http://ichitcltk.hustle.ne.jp/gudon/rd/java/Android/images/Android_baselineAligned3.jpg) link.

Here in the image the  "android:baselineAlignedChildIndex"  attribute value is set as **android:baselineAlignedChildIndex="1"** so the textview is aligned in accordingly with **button2** rather than with **button1**.If we change the value as **android:baselineAlignedChildIndex="0"** the text is aligned in accordingly with **button1**.(Usually index starts at "0")

Please refer  [this](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=http://ichitcltk.hustle.ne.jp/gudon2/index.php%3FpageType%3Dfile%26id%3DAndroid057_layout6&prev=search) link for more information.